# Accessibility service dispatchGesture does not work as intended, it only occationally perform the gesture?

Tags: android, android-service, accessibility

I am trying to build a one-hand option alternative with a cursor to reach high ends of the android device using a cursor. I track movements with a tracker on the lower-half on the screen using a touch listener and recognize users taps, and try to perform those tap on the location where the pointer is. And it works sometimes and sometimes not, And I can't figure out why?

I had included the android:canPerformGestures="true" in the service metadata.

This is the code I used to perform click gestures

```
        // duration must be set in ms according to long click or simple click
        long duration;
        if (isLongClick){
            duration = 400L;
        }else{
            duration = 103L;
        }

        GestureDescription.Builder builder = new GestureDescription.Builder();

        Point point = new Point(cursorParams.x,cursorParams.y);

        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo( point.x, point.y);
        path.lineTo( point.x + 50, point.y + 50);

        GestureDescription.StrokeDescription clickStroke =
                new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path,10, duration);

        builder.addStroke(clickStroke);
        GestureDescription description = builder.build();
        boolean isDispatched = dispatchGesture(description, new GestureResultCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GestureDescription gestureDescription) {
                super.onCompleted(gestureDescription);
                Log.d("GestureClick","Gesture completed successfully");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(GestureDescription gestureDescription) {
                super.onCancelled(gestureDescription);
                Log.d("GestureClick","Gesture failed");
            }
        },null);
```

I tried with changing start time and duration, and also changing the path with and without lineTo statement. But things end up with the same result. And I also tried returning both true or false in the touch listener where I captured the gestures in case it interrupt the dispatch gestures.

In all these attempts the result is same, Sometimes the gesture works perform a tap on the intended spot in the screen and most of the time it doesn't. And It always catches the onCompleted method on GestureResultCallback.

Comment: Have you found out the solution?